# Shell script to check if process is running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

There is some weird behavior going on that leads me to think there may be something going on...

So I have a shell script executed by cron. Basically it is meant to check if Node.js is running. If so, log the date... if not then log nothing! At the time I built it I tested it and saw it logged when a node script was running and did not log when it stopped running...

Recently I knew Node went down and thought it was the perfect opportunity to check if the script did what its supposed to do. It **didnt**! And it **does not**... :(

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ps -Al | grep -v grep | grep -q node 
then
        date > /etc/nodeCheck.log 
else
        date > /dev/null 
fi
```

Permissions on this .sh are correct, paths used exist, running

```
$ps -A | grep -v grep | grep -q node
```

returns nothing and

```
$echo $?
1
```

So shouldn't it be going to the else block? node is a process started after bootup. The shell script does not work correctly both when run by cron or by me when I am SSH'd in.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

TIA

Niko

Comment: FYI, you can combine the two `grep`s into `grep -q '[n]ode'`.

Comment: Try removing the `-q`. If it matches anything it will display it, and `cron` will mail the output to you.

Comment: Well you can check the output of `ps -A` if it does really show processes from all users. If not the problem is within the permission scope of your process `ps`.

Comment: @konsolebox how do I check the permission scope of ps? I can tell you that when I SSH in `ps` does NOT show the node process started by rc.local after booting but `ps -A` does show it

Comment: Well if `ps -A` shows it and `node` is in it then `grep` without `-q` certainly would show it as well.

Comment: @konsolebox after I kill node I do `ps -A` and do NOT see node. Yet when I execute my script it behaves as if it saw node. I execute the commands in the script manually and using `echo $?` I see that manually they do not in fact see node!

Comment: You may actually be killing and checking your node too quickly. Try to insert a sleep between them. Some processes trap SIGTERM signals and do cleanups before exiting.

Comment: In the script, you use `ps -Al`; at the command line, you omit the `l`.  Maybe the difference in the output is due to the difference in the command line options to `ps`?

Comment: hi @BroSlow your suggestion worked perfect for me, could you please add it as an answer, if you would like, and I will mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're running `BSD ps`, you should be able to use a `-C` flag or `pgrep`

```
-C cmdlist      Select by command name. This selects the processes whose executable 
                name is given in cmdlist.
```

For example,

```
if ps -C node > /dev/null
then
        date > /etc/nodeCheck.log 
else
        date > /dev/null 
fi
```

or

```
if pgrep node > /dev/null
then
        date > /etc/nodeCheck.log 
else
        date > /dev/null 
fi
```

Comment: I like this `pgrep` idea. I love all the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but perhaps it's a solution to your problem.

One of the issues I've had with Node is that the server process doesn't store its pid anywhere.  So rather than having a thing that cron runs to "check" whether it's running, I wrapped the `node` executable in a script that simply relaunches it if it crashes.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /path/to/my/software

while sleep 1; do
  date '+%Y-%m-%d %T - nodejs restarted' 
  logger "nodejs restarted"; date '+%Y-%m-%d %T - nodejs restarted' | Mail -v -s "nodejs restarted on `hostname -s`" admin@example.com
  node main.js
done
```

This script gets run *once*, when the system starts up.  It launches Node, and if Node never crashes, all is well and good, but if it does, I get a notification, a log entry, and a restart.

I run this in FreeBSD, but it should run equally well in Linux or other operating systems.

Comment: I love this idea.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check process by name:

```
if killall -s 0 node &>/dev/null; then
    ...
```

Or if shell doesn't support `&>`:

```
if killall -s 0 node >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```